# Stripe connect payment token generating token not completing transaction for test mode wtih charge

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using Stripe connect payment gateway i want to send custom values to checkout form for that i have used js element stripe with pay button.In stripe connect dashboard it shows v1/token and no payment is showing for test mode.How can i call charge method with this js element for live as well as live mode.

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <h2 class="heading">Schedule Course</h2>

    <label for="name">Tutor Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="selectedTutor" value="<?php echo $tutorName;?>" required>
   <label for="phone">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="slectedSubject" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($userId, 'userinfo' , true );?>" id="selectedSubject" required>
   <label for="email">Booking Dates</label>
    <input type="text" name="slectedDates" value="" id="selectedAppointment" required>
<label for="email">Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="slectedDates" value="<?php echo get_user_meta( $userId, 'price_individualcourse' , true);?>" id="selectedAppointment" required>
<label>
    <input name="cardholder-name" class="field is-empty" placeholder="Jane Doe" />
    <span><span>Name</span></span>
  </label>

  <label>
    <div id="card-element" class="field is-empty"></div>
    <span><span>Credit or debit card</span></span>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Pay <?php echo get_user_meta( $userId, 'price_individualcourse' , true);?></button>
  <div class="outcome">
    <div class="error" role="alert"></div>
    <div class="success">
      Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_uFOdE1YPIXhbssFt1FwH9RGQ');
var elements = stripe.elements();
var card = elements.create('card', {
  iconStyle: 'solid',
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#8898AA',
      color: 'black',
      lineHeight: '36px',
      fontWeight: 300,
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSize: '19px',

      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#8898AA',
      },
    },
    invalid: {
      iconColor: '#e85746',
      color: '#e85746',
    }
  },
  classes: {
    focus: 'is-focused',
    empty: 'is-empty',
  },
});
card.mount('#card-element');

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.field');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    input.classList.add('is-focused');
  });
  input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    input.classList.remove('is-focused');
  });
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if (input.value.length === 0) {
      input.classList.add('is-empty');
    } else {
      input.classList.remove('is-empty');
    }
  });
});

function setOutcome(result) {
  var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  successElement.classList.remove('visible');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {

    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
    successElement.classList.add('visible');
  } else if (result.error) {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

card.on('change', function(event) {
  setOutcome(event);
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  var extraDetails = {
    name: form.querySelector('input[name=cardholder-name]').value,
  };
  stripe.createToken(card, extraDetails).then(setOutcome);
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stripe Elements only collects the payment information and returns you a token, it does not charge the card. You need to pass the token from inside your `setOutcome` function to your backend PHP script and call the Stripe API there to create the charge.

You can have a look at the Stripe docs for an end-to-end PHP integration with Checkout : https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/php, which will point you in the right direction for how to pass your payment form data back to your server.